# Search by ID, no keyword. Tried using :conditions but no result ouput

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Using Thinking Sphinx, Rails 2.3.8.

I don't have a keyword to search, but I wanna search by `shop_id` which is indexed. Here's my code:

```
  @country = Country.search '', {
    :with           => {:shop_id => params[:shop_id]},
    :group_by       => 'state_id',
    :group_function => :attr,
    :page           => params[:page]
  }
```

The one above works. But I thought the `''` is rather redundant. So I replaced it with `:conditions` resulting as:

```
  @country = Country.search :conditions => {
    :with           => {:shop_id => params[:shop_id]},
    :group_by       => 'state_id',
    :group_function => :attr,
    :page           => params[:page]
  }
```

But then it gives 0 result. What is the correct code?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your define_index look like?

Answer (score 0):

Have a go in the console and see if you cant shift the :conditions around. It looks like by removing the blank string you simply have set a default param for the gem. Get the Gem in your Vendor and have a look at the Country Class to see what is accepts.